# How do I use a jQuery function inside content page of the master page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I'm using a master page for my login. The login form inside the child page requires the following method in order to be activated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function () {
                  $('#signinform').validate();
              });
</script>
```

but since `signinform` is inside the child page how can I call it from the master page? Do I actually have other possibilities to call it directly from the child page?

### Info

**My web application specification:**

- ASP.Net Web Forms
- .Net Framework 4.6

### Login.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.master.cs" Inherits="Web_WebApp.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Web - <%: Page.Title %></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="assets/global/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/global/css/ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-loading/lada.min.css" rel="stylesheet">




    <%--    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>--%>
</head>
<body class="account separate-inputs" data-page="login">





            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>




    <script src="assets/global/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/gsap/main-gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/backstretch/backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-loading/lada.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/js/pages/login-v1.js"></script>


     <script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function () {
                  $('#signinform').validate();
              });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Login.aspx (Content Page)

```
<%@ Page Title="Log In" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Login.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web_WebApp.Account.Login" Async="true" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Account/OpenAuthProviders.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="OpenAuthProviders" %>




<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">



      <!-- BEGIN LOGIN BOX -->
        <div class="container" id="login-block">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <div class="account-wall">
                        <i class="user-img icons-faces-users-03"></i>

                        <form id="signinform" runat="server" class="form-validation animated fadeIn">

                        <div class="form-signin">
                            <div class="append-icon">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control form-white username" placeholder="Username" required>
                                <i class="icon-user"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="append-icon m-b-20">
                                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-white password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                <i class="icon-lock"></i>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block ladda-button" data-style="expand-left">Sign In</button>


                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <p class="pull-left m-t-20"><a id="password" href="#">Forgot password?</a></p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-password">
                            <div class="append-icon m-b-20">
                                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-white password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                <i class="icon-lock"></i>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" id="submit-password" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block ladda-button" data-style="expand-left">Send Password Reset Link</button>
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <p class="pull-left m-t-20"><a id="login" href="#">Already got an account? Sign In</a></p>
                                <p class="pull-right m-t-20"><a href="user-signup-v1.html">New here? Sign up</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I appreciate your efforts in reaching a solution for my question.

Comment: Is your form in an iframe? Orher than that I'm assuming your templates are compiled to a single HTML file and there should be no reason the JS placed in a master page to reach a child.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by child page?

Comment: No, it's not inside the iframe. The form is inside child page which contains username,password and button to login.

Comment: @jfriend00 child page = content page

Comment: You can try to use the ready function on your '' child page'' like $('#child').ready as I can understand your child page is in the same file

Comment: So, the "child page" is just a regular part of a web page, like in a `<div>` tag?  No iframe, no actual frame, not a separate HTML page, not a popup window?  So, it's not really a page at all, but just the content area of your HTML page?  "Page" has a specific meaning in HTML (it's a whole HTML page with it's own `<body>` content and it's own JS context) and it appears you are confusing folks by calling something a ."page" that is really just a content area within a "page"

Comment: @jfriend00 "child page" is a separated file which can be placed anywhere by calling it. The master page has a placeholder which reads from child page. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use document.ready function on child pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756308/how-to-use-document-ready-function-on-child-pages)

Comment: @jfriend00 you are correct, it can also be called content page.

Comment: Well, if you want help here, then you will have to describe what the resulting HTML page looks like, not the non-standard terminology some page building system is using.  This is important because it takes completely different techniques to manipulate something that is actually it's own HTML page vs. something that is just part of another HTML page.  We honestly can't know how to help you until we know which this is.

Comment: @AtanuRoy, it didn't help.

Comment: @jfriend00 how can I help you with more information? Let me rephrase my question. How can I place jQuery function inside my content page?

Comment: then what is the error msg if place jQuery function inside content page

Comment: Do you have a `ContentPlaceHolder` in the `<head>` tag of your `Master Page`? @KevinMaxwell

Comment: @JOELEE it breaks the process. 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Comment: @AtanuRoy I tried with contentplaceholder and it was the same and then tried without and still the same.

Comment: As @jfriend00 mentioned, `$' is undefined` might be the root cause of your problem. Where have you included JQuery library?

Comment: you need to include jQuery.

Comment: or maybe jQuery.noConflict(); , try  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a section or `ContentPlaceholder` in your master page, perhaps in the footer underneath your jQuery `<script...` tag, and then use that section name in the content page to inject the content into the master. Basically, you create another placeholder exactly as you have for `MainContent`

Master page:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="BLAH/BLAH/jquery.js"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MyScripts" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Content page:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="MyScripts" runat="server">
  <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $('#signinform').validate();
          });
  </script>
</asp:Content>
```

However, your jQuery script include does not appear to be working, most likely you are working within a subfolder, and should change all of your scripts to start with a `/` so that they are relative to the web root, not your current folder.

Comment: Thanks, I actually use ASP.Net. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I like your approach but I still get the same error message.

Comment: When I put the content before the main content I get the same jQuery error and when I put it at the end I get the following error: Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.

Comment: When I put at the end, after my first content I get the following: 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Comment: The file inside that path exists. This error shows on IE before running: Error: '$' is undefined

Comment: The funny thing is that the same error works perfectly on Chrome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84948/discussion-between-peter-bailey-and-kevin-maxwell).

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you're seeing an error `$ is not defined`, then you apparently do not have jQuery included in your page before you are trying to use it.  Including jQuery at the appropriate spot in your page could be your entire problem.

---

If your "child page" is really just a template within the main HTML page (no iframe, no popup page, just one actual HTML page), then it's all one HTML page (the content is all combined before being sent to the browser as one piece of HTML) and if jQuery has already been loaded into the page then you can just use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#signinform').validate();
});
```

Anywhere you want in the page as long as jQuery has already been loaded before you insert this.  When the page is done being loaded and parsed by the browser, the `$(document).ready()` call will trigger and `$('#signinform')` should be reachable in the form at that time.

---

If your page structure is more complicated than that (like using embedded documents such as iframes) or dynamically loading some of the content via client-side JS, then you will have to describe more about how that works before we can advise on how to know when it is loaded.

Also, if you see JS errors in your page, please describe exactly what you see in the error console.

Comment: Quick Question : Does this approach works if the Master Page already contains another `$(document).ready();`? Which one will work in that case? @jfriend00

Comment: It's not complicated, it should be simple as you described. My master page is the main template/theme and the content page is just a portion of the same page which contains a form with username,password and button.

Comment: @AtanuRoy - you can have as many `$(document).ready()` statements as you want.  They will be called in the order they were originally run when the page is done being parsed.

Comment: @KevinMaxwell - A comment of yours refers to `$ is not defined`.  That sounds like you don't have jQuery loaded before you try to use jQuery and that could be the entire problem.

Answer (score 0):

//runtime error: '$' is undefined

you need to include jQuery: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or maybe run  jQuery.noConflict(); on  somewhere .   try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
   $('#signinform').validate();
 })
```